# URL rewrite not working -htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite my site URL structure to a SEO friendly url using htaccess file.
I want to rewrite this URL:

/Site/mysite/tags.php?tag=tag

to

/Site/mysite/tags/tag

This is my script:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /tag/(.*)\.php tags.php?tag=$1
```

other commands such as DirectoryIndex working properly but my above code not.

i know this question asked before but i can not fix this problem. excuse me please!
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your script would rewrite `/tag/foo.php` to `tags.php?tag=foo`. What you need is

```
RewriteRule ^/tag/(.*) /tags.php?tag=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code rather :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^Site/mysite/tag/(.*)$ /Site/mysite/tags.php?tag=$1
```